# Custom function conversion error?

Tags: c++

I'm having troubles implementing a conversion function.

In the `zj_X` function I want to pass the string as an argument to the function and convert it to the `char[]` type is used to convert hexadecimal, but it seems that the results obtained after running debug do not seem to be very good.

This is the error that IDE reported to me:

H:\CPP\tst_jz\main.cpp|11|error: 'q1' was not declared in this scope|

The IDE that I use is code blocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
void zj_10(int i,int j);
void zj_x();

int main()
{
    zj_10(20,2);
    zj_x(q1,8);
    return 0;
}

void   zj_10(int i,int j)
{
    char num[100];
    cout<<"转换后的结果为:";
    itoa(i,num,j);
   cout<<num<<endl;
}

void zj_x(string str,int i)
{
    char buf[10];
    int  length = str.copy(buf, 9);
    buf[length] = '\0';
    char *p1;
    cout<<"转换的结果为:"<<strtol(buf,&p1,i);
}
```

Comment: What is `q1`?  You use it, but you never create it.

Comment: You must declare `q1` above `zj_x(q1,8);` in your file. (doesn't matter what compiler (or IDE) you are using, you should still get the same or similar error)

Comment: q1 is a string of type only,Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it **if you declare it (and initialize it) before you use it...**  Try this `int main() { string q1 = "mystring"; ...` and compile again.

Comment: before passing just declare it something like `char q1[]="string"`

Comment: I found the answer to the question. Obviously this question is stupid. Thank you, my friends

Comment: The only stupid question is the one you don't have the courage to ask...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you don't have a variable named q1 in your main function but you are passing that it. That is what the error is. So try declaring and defining that variable first or if you want to pass q1 as string then send `"q1"` instead of just `q1`

Comment: You may want to touch on the prototype `void zj_x();` not matching the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If q1 is a string literal, then enclose it in DOUBLE quotation marks like "q1".

aravind_reddy told you to use single quotation marks:

> if you want to pass q1 as string then send 'q1' instead of just q1

but those are only used in character literals, like 'a', '1', etc.
String literals must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

If q1 is a name for a string variable, then you obviously need to declare it.